# pyhive, Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration

Tags: hive, pyhive, apache-dolphinscheduler

I use pyhive with dolphinscheduler in my program, it works good in develop environment, but it sometimes failed, sometimes succeed in production environment. I do not know why?

Example code

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host="cdh1", port=10000, username="root")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
""")
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO TABLE table_name
SELECT ...
""")
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Software version

```
CDH6.3  
hive version 2.1.1  
hadoop version 3.0.0
```

/tmp/hive/XXX  log

```
ERROR [main]  hadoop.ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
```

[image: pyhive error msg]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you have to make sure your CDH cluster is healthy